# Bessel-like differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I have the following Bessel-like differential equation:

$$r^2T^{''}+K_1rT^{'}+(K_2r^2+K_3r^m)T=0$$

In this equation, $T=f(r)$ and $K_1$, $K_2$, $K_3$, and $m$ are parameters. I need an analytical solution for it. $T$ should be obtained as an explicit function of $r$. May somebody help me to find a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $m$ a positive integer ?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: Thus real positive ? Or plainly real ?

Comment: All parameters are real numbers. Anyway, if a spacial limit leads to a straight solution, it's acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Some special cases:

$m=0,2$ : convertible to Bessel ODE

$m=1$ : convertible to degenerate hypergeometric ODE

$m=4$ : ODE of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0216.pdf

$m=-2$ : similar to [Hunt for exact solutions of second order ordinary differential equations with varying coefficients.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2934638) and can reduce to the doubly-confluent Heun equation